# drawImage() isn't working for canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

here is my code below I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  when I preview it, the image isn't there, just the canvas border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<body>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sticky = new Image();
sticky.src = "sticky.png";
sticky.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(sticky, 0, 0);
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is onload executing? Check that sticky.png is a valid path to your image.

Comment: when I use the html <img> tag, the image shows up, but I want it in the javascript so I can make it move and stuff.  Clearly the path to the image itself is fine, but maybe syntax in my javascript is wrong?

Comment: No, your syntax is fine...I substituted my own image and your exact code ran fine. There's a tiny likelihood that you have a timing issue so try putting .src after .onload (not likely to change anything, but worth a try).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the console displays the link to your file. look there if the correct**

Maybe you should have to wait until the image is loaded before you draw it. Try this instead:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    make_base();
    function make_base()
    {
      base_image = new Image();
      base_image.src = 'http://techtastico.com/files/2014/06/Apple-Swift-Logo.png';
      base_image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
      };
    }
```

```html
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
    style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>
```

Comment: How does your answer effectively differ from the questioners code?